# Add value to input

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do simple math with this. The problem I got is that the result is never shown.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="data1" type="number" name="data1">
        <br>
        <input id="data2" type="number" name="data2">
        <br>
        <input id="button" type="submit">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input id="result" type="number" name="result" value="1">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS: Here I got my variables. The result of the equation should shown at the #result input.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    var result = 0;
    $("#result").val( result ); 

    $("#button").click(function() {

        var data1 = $("#data1").val();
        var data2 = $("#data2").val();

        result = $(data1 * data2);

        $("#result").val( result ); 

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your following fragment, `result` will be an object

```
result = $(data1 * data2);
```

change it to:

```
result = data1 * data2;
```

The rest of the code looks fine. As suggested in the other comments, do not forget to add the call to `preventDefault()`

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var result = 0;
    $("#result").val( result ); 

    $("#button").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var data1 = $("#data1").val();
        var data2 = $("#data2").val();

        result = data1 * data2;    
        $("#result").val(result); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a prevent default to stop the page from submitting and reloading.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

var result = 0;
$("#result").val( result ); 

$("#button").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var data1 = $("#data1").val();
    var data2 = $("#data2").val();

    result = $(data1 * data2);

    $("#result").val( result ); 

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A `form` has some default parameters. It has that, even if you don't pass anything to it like you do. For example, it has an `action` - that defaults to the site you're on right now. So the form will submit (an `GET` request - which is another default - to the url you're on) if you click the submit button. No matter how few parameters you pass to it. To prevent a form doing this. You can use the `preventDefault()` method.

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... rest of your code
}
```

This will stop your form from really submitting the data/form/itself - and you can process its values with js on the same page.